# How to execute Converter when value of the another control get's changed?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have two `ComboBox` ComboBox1 and ComboBox2, I want to execute ComboBox2 converter whenever ComboBox1 `SelectedItem` gets changed, How it can be done in XAML.

So far I have this XAML for ComboBox2:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Converter={StaticResource MYConverter}, ConverterParameter= {Binding ElementName=comboBox1, Path=SelectedItem,Mode=TwoWay}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A binding is re-evaluated only when the value of the binding is changed, not the converter parameter, so suppose:

1. `SelectedItem1` property of the ViewModel is bound to `ComboBox1`s`SelectedItem` property.
2. `SelectedItem2` property of the ViewModel is bound to `ComboBox2`s `SelectedItem` property.
3. `ComboBox2`s `ItemSource` property of the ViewModel is bound to a property on your ViewModel called `MyItems`:

Whenever `SelectedItem1` is changed, you should raise `PropertyChanged` event for `MyItems`. This way, the binding is re-evaluated and the converter is executed.

P.S: Please give more context about your questions in the future, e.g. what your ViewModel looks like.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the missing information, Actually my `ComboBox` is in a UserControl and it's `ItemSource` is in the parents VM but ComboBox1 SelectedItem1 is part of UserControl VM, so how can I update the property of parent's VM from this VM.

Comment: @Dishant I can think of 3 ways:
 1. Have a method on the parent VM that raises PropertyChanged event and call that method in the usercontrol VM

2. Have an event in the usercontrol VM that you raise everytime `SelectedItem1` changes and handle it in the parent VM and raise property changed event there

3. Let the user control VM have `MyItems` property and bind the usercontrols to that

Comment: Thanks. I will try to see what fits my scenario.

Comment: As the solution that you suggested didn't fit my business case, what I did is followed the approach as mentioned in [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17449) post.

Comment: @Dishant I'd say this is close to method 1, the detail view model has a reference to the parent view model.

Answer (score 0):

On the code-behind, you could create something like this:

```
comboBox1.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(comboBox1SelectionChanged);
```

It will generate an event handler that wiil be called by delegate, the handler should look like this:

```
void comboBox1SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Your logic here
    }
```

Don’t forget:

u

```
sing System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer if this can be achieved from XAML because I am using MVVM pattern.